# flex grid ruins progress bars

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to get the result:

> **** ****
>
> ---

however I either get:

> ** 
>    ** 
>    ** 
>    **

or other stuff like that. 
I want to keep the 'progression bars' at full length
and 2 by 2, not all under each other 
i feel like this has to do something with flex/ grids but i can't seem to figure it out

here is the live-snippet: 82729.ict-lab.nl 
here is my code:

```css
    .skills>.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.skills>* {
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 15px;
    width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    text-align: left;

    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.progress {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(43,194,83);

    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
                inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="skills">
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
      <p>CSS</p>
      <div class="progress-bar">
        <span class="progress" style="width: 66%"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
      <p>HTML</p>
      <div class="progress-bar">
        <span class="progress" style="width: 66%"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
      <p>JS</p>
      <div class="progress-bar">
        <span class="progress" style="width: 66%"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-wrapper">
    <div class="progress-wrapper">
      <p>PHP</p>
      <div class="progress-bar">
        <span class="progress" style="width: 66%"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: had to post css out of the ``` otherwise couldn't post

Comment: You've need to apply `display:grid` etc on the progress wrappers...it;s not inherited.